# how is this code used to plot a grid with obstacles?

Tags: matlab

this is the said matlab block of code used to plot a grid

```
scatter(obstacles(:,1),obstacles(:,2),100,obstacleColor,'filled');
grid ;
axis([0 5 0 5]);
hold on;
```

I finished the matlab on the ramp tutorial and still couldn't figure out what this code is doing

Comment: Hi Jasmine, could you tell us a little more about the tutorial? It sounds like you're trying to plot data points in the plane, with some attributes.

Comment: this is a chunck of the code related to an exercise. I'm confused whats inside the scatter function. the obstacles and obstacle color were defined earlier in the code.

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: `obstacles(:,1)` and `obstacles(:,2)` seem to be the coordinates of whatever you're plotting in whatever coordinate system. `100` is just the size of the markers used in the scatter plot. `obstacleColor` is just the color to be given to the markers, and the `filled` options is just to create markers that are also colored in the inside.

Answer (score 1):

scatter(x,y,sz,c,'filled')

'x' is equal x-axis variable, according to your problem 'x' is "obstacles(:,1)".

'y' is equal y-axis variable, according to your problem 'y' is "obstacles(:,2)".

'sz' is marker area, according to your problem 'sz' is "100".

'c' is marker color, according to your problem 'c' is "obstacleColor". This variable is probably equal to like [0, 0, 1] etc.

Option to fill the interior of the markers, specified as 'filled'. We can fill in the marker this variable.

You can show  axes grid lines when you use "grid".

You can specify your axis limits with "axis".

If you will draw new plots, Previous plots do not delete while you use "hold on".

You can look this link, it will be helpful for you.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#d122e1165657

I hope, I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate as many *"Magic Numbers"* directly inputted into the `scatter()` function, below is a script that breaks the inputs into variables. Hopefully, this helps with the learning experience. The function descriptions below the script may help shed some light on each of the function's inputs.

### Scatter Plot Result:

[image: Scatter Plot]

### Full Test Script/Playground:

```
%The number of obstacles%
Number_Of_Obstacles = 100;

%Generating random test data ranging from 0 to 5%
obstacles = 5.*rand(Number_Of_Obstacles,2);

%Setting the obstacle colour/colour of the data points%
obstacleColor = 'red';

%Column 1 corresponds to the x-values/points%
X_Points = obstacles(:,1);
%Column 2 corresponds to the y-values/points%
Y_Points = obstacles(:,2);

%Setting the marker size%
Maker_Size = 100;

scatter(X_Points,Y_Points,Maker_Size,obstacleColor,'filled');

%Setting the range for the axes%
X_Minimum = 0;
X_Maximum = 5;

Y_Minimum = 0;
Y_Maximum = 5;
grid;
axis([X_Minimum X_Maximum Y_Minimum Y_Maximum]);
hold on
```

### Function Explanations:

**Function Call:** `scatter(x,y,sz,c)`

• `x` → The x-coordinates/values of the data set.

• `y` → The y-coordinates/values of the data set.

• `sz` → The size of the markers (boldness).

• `c` → The colour of the markers.

[MATLAB Documentation: Scatter](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)

**Function Call:** `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])`

• `xmin` → The minimum x-value on the horizontal scale.

• `xmax` → The maximum x-value on the horizontal scale.

• `ymin` → The minimum y-value on the vertical scale.

• `ymax` → The maximum y-value on the vertical scale.

[MATLAB Documentation: Axis](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-limits)

**Call:** `grid`

• Used to toggle the grid on and off. By default draws lines along the scale. Probably best to use `grid on` and `grid off` to ensure that grid does not toggle between on and off between consecutive runs.

[MATLAB Documentation: Grid](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/grid.html)

**Call:** `hold on`

• Used to allow any following graphs/plots in the script to be plotting on the same axis. Plot multiple graphs in a single figure.

[MATLAB Documentation: Hold](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)